# how to proxy grpcs messages in C++ in a stateless manner

Tags: grpc-c++

My question is very similar to https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/Yruej18KJ_M/m/oGp5vYocCgAJ

I want to implement a service agnostic gRPC proxy in C++, which forwards the request from the Client to the Server and forwards the response back from the server to the client ?

Is there a generic manner to do so ?

I see example mentioned in [here](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/blob/grpc-proxy/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java)

How do I achieve the same in C++ ? Unable to find the C++ equivalent APIs for

ServerCallHandler, ServerCall.Listener, ClientCallListener

unable to figure how to do this with the APIs avaialble in C++ grpc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an example project demonstrating how it needs to be constructed but features are there. Assuming that you want to make a proxy receiving all requests, you can use this `RegisterAsyncGenericService` or `RegisterCallbackGenericService` of `ServerBuilder`. You can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f99b8b5bc4a89d37f86bf063999ec22e44312663/include/grpcpp/generic/async_generic_service.h#L51-L67).